# Deleted MySQL/PhpMyAdmin default users, now having errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My DB got hacked for my stupid, now I've deleted some users that were there, like 'root' and 'phpmyadmin' <- i dont even know if this is a default user or it has been created by the hacker.

After deleting it i'm having frequently errors on /var/log/mysql/error.log like:

2018-08-10T11:11:44.202471X 136677 [Note] Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

they come like 10~20 times per hour, is this a kind of attack or it's just some thing from phpmyadmin itself?

Also I'm having this error when logging in on phpmyadmin: https://ibb.co/d8A6kp, but my application is working right.

Any tips?

Comment: Well, the user phpmyadmin is the user that phpmyadmin uses for allowing you to use it through the browser...

Comment: I'm using it trough the browser normally with the user i created...

Comment: curious... did you try this solution?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047922/access-denied-for-user-phpmyadminlocalhost-using-password-yes?rq=1
also, the hack you suffered was using phpmyadmin? because if not, you could restore it and check.